# Python Adwords API authentication issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-ads-api

I can't seem to connect with the Adwords API. I followed the steps as described here: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/first-request

Files are in the folder C:\Users\User\Documents\googleads-python-lib-master\
and the authentication file (googleads.yaml) is populated with my account settings. These account settings previously worked in Java environment.

Any suggestions about what's going wrong?

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and the latest Adwords API for Python.

The error code I'm receiving is:

```
C:/Users/User/Documents/googleads-python-lib-master/examples/adwords/v201509/basic_operations/get_campaigns.py
INFO:oauth2client.client:Refreshing access_token
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:opening (https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201509/CampaignService?wsdl)
DEBUG:suds.transport.http:sending:
URL: https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201509/CampaignService
HEADERS: {'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Soapaction': b'""', 'SOAPAction': b'""', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ya29.ngJKUmqHAKGfa93lSHVcYtpj6IHzN9KAoaMhGS_LEZJvrJjHnEl8Kx83leap3ae-g_zHmzA'}
MESSAGE:
b'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201509" xmlns:ns1="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201509" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><SOAP-ENV:Header><tns:RequestHeader><tns:developerToken>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</tns:developerToken><tns:userAgent>Client name (AwApi-Python, googleads/3.11.0, Python/3.5.1)</tns:userAgent><tns:validateOnly>false</tns:validateOnly><tns:partialFailure>false</tns:partialFailure></tns:RequestHeader></SOAP-ENV:Header><ns0:Body><ns1:get><ns1:serviceSelector><ns1:fields>Id</ns1:fields><ns1:fields>Name</ns1:fields><ns1:fields>Status</ns1:fields><ns1:paging><ns1:startIndex>0</ns1:startIndex><ns1:numberResults>100</ns1:numberResults></ns1:paging></ns1:serviceSelector></ns1:get></ns0:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>'
ERROR:suds.client:<suds.sax.document.Document object at 0x03F01390>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.5.egg\suds\transport\http.py", line 82, in send
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.6-py3.5.egg\suds\transport\http.py", line 132, in u2open
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 471, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 581, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues/10

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, if I understood correctly, it's simply not possible to authenticate using OAuth2 within Python 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by some further research. Fabrigm already helped me in the right direction. Thx!

Google Adwords API has multiple releases, for both Python 2.x and 3.x. Though when you get the latest release on Github, you'll get the the Python client library for Google's Ads APIs for Python 2.x.

When you go through other [releases of the library](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/releases), you'll find examples for both Python 2.x and 3.x. The one written in Python 3.x works absolutely fine, but (atleast for me) it was easy to make the mistake and go ahead with the other release.

I hope this might help other people, strugling with the same problem.